# Get infomation of the media file when open an OPENFILENAME dialog

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

How do i get duration,album,singer,etc of a media file,not only mp3 format but including video file also in MFC, i have opened an OPENFILENAME dialog and want to retrieve the media file' infomation when select on a media file. please help me to get over it. Thank's so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [IShellFolder2::GetDetailsOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775053%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Here is a discussion in a [German forum](http://www.c-plusplus.de/forum/206558-full) but you can easily extract sample code there.

Comment: I have resolved the issue but anyway thank you you also!